# How to iterate in Python through two lists with different length in paralell?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator

I have two lists:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6,7]
```

And I want to iterate over them. What I want to obtain is something similar to this:

```
1,4
2,5
3,6
 ,7
```

I have thought of using the `zip` function but it doesn't seem to work with different length lists as by using the following code:

```
for l1, l2 in list1, list2:
     print(l1,l2)
```

I get this:

```
1,4
2,5
3,6
```

So the number 7 is missing. I wonder how could I adapt the code or if
there is any other option I am missing to iterate in parallel when the lists are of different lengths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6,7]
for l1, l2 in zip_longest(list1, list2):
     print(l1,l2)
# 1 4
# 2 5                                                        
# 3 6                                                         
# None 7
```

Even more specific to your question, use `fillvalue` with `zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6,7]
for l1, l2 in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=' '):
     print(l1,l2)
# 1 4
# 2 5                                                         
# 3 6                                                         
#   7
```

Comment: Woah there you ninja (:

Comment: Haha, seconds difference. @zeet

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You need [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6,7]
>>> list(zip_longest(a, b))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (None, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check zip_longest() from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) (a very useful module in Python Standard Library)

```
from itertools import zip_longest
for l1, l2 in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=''):
     print(l1,l2)
```